# Iteração de arrays e objetos

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho os seguintes dados vindo da api:

```
{
"unidades": [{
    "row": {
        "0": {
            "titulo": "Unidade S\u00e3o Paulo",
            "url": "unidade-sao-paulo",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis repellat necessitatibus voluptatem, id distinctio dolore praesentium molestias exercitationem cumque quae. Illum quam nostrum iure voluptatibus dignissimos blanditiis eius rem fugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, esse. teste.",
            "mapa": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d34814.407067189415!2d-46.464300200826266!3d-23.481601745424488!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce5fdc7408f3b7%3A0x4bd6aaf16595e2f1!2sParque+Ecol%C3%B3gico+do+Tiet%C3%AA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1533210424008",
            "galeria": ["\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-sao-paulo\\bd06dd72fffd392ad69554ff04a5819b.jpg", "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-sao-paulo\\c28a8038364deb5b8ea01ed88ea40314.jpg"]
        },
        "3": {
            "titulo": "Unidade 3",
            "url": "unidade-3",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati provident adipisci cupiditate ea temporibus consequatur dolores magnam fugiat quisquam at velit voluptate deserunt, quasi amet. Molestiae aut dolor beatae quas! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nulla eaque.",
            "mapa": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d123116.66013559673!2d-98.89025651822472!3d57.95896649207766!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x525d3e1c8cf1057d%3A0x3894f5a6e00235da!2sSand+Lakes+Provincial+Wilderness+Park!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1533858514847",
            "galeria": ["\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-3\\fa87db6712e6e0518b1d7bd402230ca9.jpg", "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-3\\c82106d1b52dad5898524c1a3e29e270.jpg"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "row": {
        "1": {
            "titulo": "Unidade 1",
            "url": "unidade-1",
            "descricao": "cria\u00e7\u00e3o da unidade 1 de exemplo",
            "mapa": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d243826.17580693625!2d-58.008067541334526!3d-17.27768204570092!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x93850fb366fa0f2f%3A0x352da546bf8209ff!2sState+of+Mato+Grosso!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1533858016289",
            "galeria": [
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-1\\8caed56b129c737f93efcbd5aba2b8a4.jpg", 
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-1\\d3e498aa3e303004d471757d17f95330.jpg", 
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-1\\1dfd285ce4480c8b3ec173e4b19b8c0e.jpg"
            ]
        },
        "4": {
            "titulo": "Unidade 4",
            "url": "unidade-4",
            "descricao": "descri\u00e7\u00e3o de teste unidade 4",
            "mapa": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7867.687634209555!2d-45.57934610711002!3d60.463011640048414!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4eaa4f969396ea09%3A0xd63558965b94e1a6!2sAlluitsup+Paa%2C+Greenland!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1533858440104",
            "galeria": [
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-4\\b84b5813aacefa9e7c8357379b208fd9.jpg",
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-4\\5535148b092fc381a5381bb51d25261d.jpg",
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-4\\f8870532520f1dbf3bdb45cce19c2f42.jpg",
                "\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-4\\8298904c8ef69ecb5288eae42708b878.jpg"
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    "row": {
        "2": {
            "titulo": "Unidade 2",
            "url": "unidade-2",
            "descricao": "unidade 2 teste",
            "mapa": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d15336.03774711962!2d18.49229377920496!3d16.065000091055342!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x11476b40f9d760bd%3A0x8287051ddad8a038!2sKoro+Toro%2C+Chad!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sbr!4v1533858133835",
            "galeria": ["\\assets\\images\\unidades\\unidade-2\\bae42802dc43834615565a33aed780af.jpg"]
        }
    }
}]
}
```

estou tentando fazera iteração desses dados porem recebo o erro:

> "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

dessa forma:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let rows of unidades">         
        <div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let unidade of rows"> <!-- nessa linha -->
```

Comment: Será que não seria necessário indicar a palavra `unidades` no plural? Pode ser por isso que ele não está encontrando o objeto...

Comment: `unidades` é um array logo pode iterar, mas cada um dos elementos dentro de `unidades` é um objeto logo não pode iterar, que é o erro que lhe aparece.

Comment: @Isac é exatamente isso, eu não estou conseguindo montar o loop para fazer essa conversão =\, acontece com `galeria` também

Comment: Cada `row` é um objeto logo não tem como iterar com `NgFor`. Para o código que tem, tinha que converter cada `row` num array com as implicações que isso traz, como por exemplo perder a chave associada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu JSON não está no formato para você rodar o ngFor desta forma.

Como o próprio erro diz:

> "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let rows of unidades">
```

esta parte funciona, pois dentro de `unidades` existe um array:

```
"unidades": [...]
```

mas `rows['row']`

```
 "row": { ... }
```

é um objeto `{}` e não um array `[]` e a linha abaixo não irá funcionar

```
<div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let unidade of rows['row']">
```

A sintaxe espera `*ngFor="let <Object> of <Array>"`

Você deve transformar o `rows['row']` em um array antes.

**EDIT:**

Você pode usar esse snipet

```
this.data.unidades.forEach((e)=>{
    let row = Object.values(e)[0];
    this.rows_transformed.push(Object.values(row));
});

this.rows_transformed = [].concat.apply([],this.rows_transformed);
```

Depois faça o `ngFor` em `rows_transformed`.

Fiz um exemplo pra voce [**Aqui**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/A2je4BxCZsHqlH47?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: ja tentei fazer diversos loops para transformar o `row` em index mas ainda não consegui

Comment: Já editei a resposta, dá uma olhada... botei pra rodar no plunker [http://next.plnkr.co/edit/A2je4BxCZsHqlH47?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/A2je4BxCZsHqlH47?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: é quase isso que preciso, porem quebrou o layout, porque cada linha é composta por duas colunas, por isso é essa estrutura `row[0,1], row[2,3]` etc,

Comment: Se você não fizer "this.rows_transformed = [].concat.apply([],this.rows_transformed);", você terá esses arrays... Mas aí tem que fazer outro ngFor, no exemplo tá com 1 só. Boa sorte aí.

Comment: sim, na verdade ja estava com dois `*ngFor` tirando a linha `this.rows_transformed = [].concat.apply([],this.rows_transformed)` funcionou perfeitamente, cara muito obrigado pela ajuda! estava quebrando a cabeça a horas, agora posso dormir tranquilo xD

Comment: Boa! Boa noite.